# Setting pointer-events dynamically on iOS 15 Safari is unreliable and unpredictable

Tags: css, safari, ios15, pointer-events

In Safari on iOS 15, links that are in a container that has `pointer-events: none;` applied, don't become tappable when `pointer-events` is set to `all` dynamically at a later stage. Actually, in some cases they do, but it's *very* unpredictable. For instance, when the container is an `ul` and the links are inside a `li` element, they do become tappable. Or when the link has a `button` sibling. I know this sounds strange, but it's true. I made a demo, so you can try it for yourself: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mdhjqs?file=index.html

Am I missing something? Is this a bug unique to Safari on iOS 15?

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled on the same issue with Safari iOS 15, this doesn't happen on mobile Chrome or on desktop Safari.

The solution I found to obtain the same behaviour is to set the inline style with JS, like the following:

```
if (el.classList.contains("is-clickable")) {
    el.style.pointerEvents = "all";
} else {
    el.style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
```

I've also removed any property specification in CSS. Once the property is set to `none` anywhere in the CSS using inline styles doesn't work anymore, which is odd as one would expect inline styles to always take precedence over classes.

For me this is also an issue with the structure `ul > li > a`, both in my test case and on Senne's example.

I've also tried setting pointer events to `auto` or `initial` with no success.